# Dual Booting Ubuntu from Disc Error. Please Help

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I have an exam in two days and need Ubuntu to do it and I can't get it to work!

Laptop: HP 15-n096sa
OS installed: Windows 10

Task: dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows 10
Media Used: DVD-R(ubuntu iso burned on it)

I'm following the steps from here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/installation

I have completed every step exactly as laid out.
Everything was working perfectly until the very end. It said installation complete with a restart button. I clicked restart and took out the dvd from the drive. It then started loading what looked to be a full screen terminal and there was commands running throught it). I turned it off then tried to boot up, it booted straight to windows. I then put the disc back in to boot to disc and got an error message saying:

```
Failed to open\EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load....and so on
```

I looked everywhere and cannot find a solution!

Comment: You may check the boot order in Boot Manager settings from BIOS.  If Grub is selected as first, Ubuntu should boot first.  If some other entry is selected as first, you can change it to Grub and try again.  Note: you will see Windows as an option if Grub is loaded successfully.

Comment: Theres no grub in the boot order? It has Internal CD - OS Boot Manager - USB Diskette on Key - USB CD/DVD - Network Adapter

Comment: If Ubuntu is successfully installed, Ubuntu (I mean Grub loader) entry should be there. If it is not there, installation is not complete.  I think you can try to change the boot order to the USB or DVD which has ubuntu and check if any OS is loaded.  If not, you need to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: Yeah it's not there. When I change boot order to DVD I get the Failed to open error

Comment: I suggest to load the CD/DVD once again and check if it is detected. (and proceed to install again)  If it is not detected, the problem could be BIOS settings(boot order) or non-bootable image in DVD or UEFI setting issues(UEFI=enabled, FastBoot=disabled in my PC). All the best.

Comment: Still get the error. I just don’t understand how it worked before(booted fine) now it won’t boot? The disc hasn’t changed at all

Comment: You may disable UEFI in BIOS and try again.  Normally UEFI works with USB boot.  I am not sure about DVD boot.

Comment: If above approach fails, you can prepare bootable USB with rufus. Change the boot order to USB in BIOS and install.  After the installation, update Ubuntu as first boot order in BIOS.  This should work fine.  This will avoid DVD issues.

Comment: Ok, I’ll give it a go

Comment: Finally got it to work. But grub does not come up automatically? I have to get into it manaually?

Comment: With the experience I had with 18.10, Ubuntu(Grub loader) is not the first entry in boot order by default.  I had to change it.  By the way, which solution helped you to resolve the problem?

Comment: I changed the media to a usb hard disc(hdd) and I was able to install Ubuntu properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to any of the following issues:

1. **Problem**: After Ubuntu installation, Ubuntu (Grub loader) is not the first entry in BIOS boot manager.
   **Solution**: change the boot order in BIOS so that Ubuntu is selected as first entry.
   **Hint**: With certain Lenovo computers, you need to press novo key (near charging port) to enter BIOS after Ubuntu installation.
2. **Problem**: DVD is not recognized.
   **Solution 1**: Create bootable image and burn DVD or create bootable USB (recommended) with Rufus.
   **Solution 2**: change UEFI settings in BIOS and try again.
3. **Problem**: Ubuntu installation is not complete. Or Ubuntu Grub loader is corrupted.
   **Solution**: Reinstall Ubuntu