# System BootOrder not found installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I have already installed Windows 10 on my PC. Today, I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows. After completing the installation the PC is unable to boot and after showing this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mufRA.jpg) message it keeps restarting in loop. It is important to inform that Windows was installed using Legacy BIOS mode where as the Ubuntu was installed using EFI. Now, there are separate BIOS modes for each system and I am unable to boot windows even from "Boot from File" option in the Boot Order menu. When I boot from the legacy boot entry of windows in boot order it says boot device not found please install operating system.
I am using HP Probook g5.

Please help.

Comment: You can check if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118805/dual-booting-ubuntu-from-disc-error-please-help/1118899#1118899 helps.

Comment: @felix, thanks for responding. I am able to boot Ubuntu manually but when selecting windows from boot options it doesn't boot and says boot device not found.

Comment: in bios you need to set up some "legacy support" mode to support your windows installation.